# Write to a file as a different user in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, file-permissions

I am trying to write bytes to a file. Generally, one could simply do:

```py
...
fb = file.read() # this contains the bytes to copy

with open("/tmp/", "wb") as out:
    out.write(fb)
```

It works perfectly, but I am trying to make it work with `subprocess`. Why? Because I need the output file to be created under the ownership of a different user - say `userA`. And the only way possible I am seeing is user impersonation. An example below:

```py
# runs as root

import subprocess

def run(cmd, **kwargs):
    popen = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd.split(),
        stdout=kwargs.pop("stdout", subprocess.PIPE),
        stderr=kwargs.pop("stderr", subprocess.PIPE),
        user=kwargs.get("user")
    )
    popen.communicate()


dst = "/data/userA" # special (network) location that only userA can access (not even root)
byte_data = file.read() # this contains the bytes to copy
user = "userA"

with open(dst, mode="wb") as out_f:
    cmd = f"echo -n {byte_data}"
    run(cmd=cmd, user=user, stdout=out_f)
```

If I send a `txt` file, my content is `b"text content"`.

My limitations:

- File can be of any format: text, images, video, etc. therefore I can't decode it.
- I can't create the file as `root` and `chown` it to `userA` since not even root can access that location.

Comment: Your context manager is in the main process. i.e `with open("/tmp/", mode="wb")` , so your file is opened and closed by the main user itself. So file will be created by that user.

Comment: @Kris ok that was my fear too .. in that case the whole approach needs to be rethought

Comment: Would you perhaps share some code snippet? :) I am not fully following your train of thought

Comment: [A normal user usually cannot "give away" files to someone else on a UNIX system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27374/403072). The solution is to use group permissions (i.e. create the file with a group containing both the file creator and `userA`, and appropriate file modes) or ACLs. Arguably this is unrelated to Python or `subprocess`.

Comment: Location ```/data/``` is a mounted network share where ACLs are managed externally so the assumption is that no other user than ```userA``` can rw into ```/data/userA```

Comment: If your user running the program cannot write to `/data/userA`, you cannot write to that location, unless you can run the application with [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) or [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) as `userA`. There is no way to circumvent the basic security principles of UNIX from Python. I think this is not Python question, but a UNIX or superuser stackexchange question. Maybe this also is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/395122) at heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shell, `sudo tee` is sometimes used to replace output redirection to ensure that the correct user opens the file.

```
# Instead of sudo -u user foo > tmp.txt
foo | sudo -u user tee tmp.txt > /dev/null
```

You can do the same thing in Python. Note that `subprocess.Popen` itself can read directly from your input file; you don't need to construct an artificial command.

```
# tee writes to any named files *and* standard output; by default,
# you probably want to redirect standard output to /dev/null
# or the equivalent.
def copy_to(src, dest_name, user, *, stdout=subprocess.devnull, **kwargs):
    subprocess.run(["tee", dest_name], user=user, stdin=src, **kwargs)

copy_to(file, "/data/userA", "userA")
```

Essentially, this `copy_to` is just a wrapper around `subprocess.run` that runs `tee` using the given input file, output file *name*, and user. Any other keyword arguments will be passed directly to `subprocess.run`.

The key is that `tee` opens the output file for writing, not your Python script.

Comment: If this works, this is the accepted answer !

Comment: It won't work *yet*; fixing it ...

Comment: Isn't sudo likely to require a password?

Comment: Worst case I get a new trail to follow :)

Comment: @ArthurKing I use ```user``` parameter which works with ```setuid``` but ```sudo``` is also possible

Comment: Ok, really fixed now, I think. I overlooked that `user` is an argument to `Popen`. (I initially confused your `run` function with `subprocess.run`, and it took a while for me to get straight what was using what.)

Comment: @chepner man it worked so gracefully . Completely forgot about our friend ```tee```.